# Android build release with iroha library

Tags: android, hyperledger-iroha

I I have problem with build release apk file on android.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
```

- when I did: `minifyEnabled true`
  after building release apk: app-release.apk, the app crashed because of generateKeyPair.
- when I did: `minifyEnabled false`
  after building release apk: app-release.apk, the build is okay.

Why does the build crash when minifyEnabled is true?

Comment: can you post error logs?

Comment: You will have to add a rule in your `proguard-rules.pro`, but without knowing your project/library package name, we are unable to help you.

Comment: is use this dependency:
implementation 'com.github.hyperledger.iroha-java:client:6.1.0'

I am so struggle on this issue. If you have any solution please share me. Thanks.
When I try to use proguard with android. it's error.